# Generating URLs from ASP.NET MVC routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

If I have some routes set up as follows:

```
context.MapRoute("Route1", "Public/DataCapture/Name", new { controller = "Profile", action = "Name" } );

context.MapRoute("Route2", "Public/DataCapture/Age", new { controller = "Profile", action = "Age" } );

context.MapRoute("Route2", "Public/DataCapture/Amount", new { controller = "Income", action = "Amount" } );
```

How can I generate URLs that use the route path and not the actual controller/action path?

E.g.

```
Url.Action("Name", "Profile")
```

Should generate "Public/DataCapture/Name" rather than "Public/Profile/Name"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [Url.RouteUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493014.aspx).

In the past, when I have had problems getting that to return the correct route, it was usually an indication that either my routes were not defined in the correct order, or I was doing something that kept the routing system from matching the route I intended.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick. Seems obvious now. Hadn't even checked for a method like that.